# Obtener el número total de filas mientras estoy paginando

Tags: php, sql, android, paginación

**Descripción del problema:**

Estoy ejecutando una consulta SQL la cual obtiene los productos de un negocio de 10 en 10 (paginación). A la vez, quiero mostrar el número total de resultados, independientemente de cuantos registros se hayan cargado por la paginación:

**Ejemplo:**

El negocio "X" tiene cargados en la base de datos un total de 100 productos, y en mi aplicación cargué los primeros 10 productos, por lo que quedan 90 restantes. Al paginar, obtengo los siguientes 10, por lo que estoy mostrando 20 productos y quedarían por mostrar 80 más.

**Pregunta:**

Cual sería la forma correcta/eficiente de obtener el total de filas (en este caso 100) mientras que estoy mostrando solo una parte del total (en este caso 20).

**Mi consulta SQL:**

```php
"SELECT * FROM products WHERE idEmpresa = $idEmpresa LIMIT $page,10"
```

Comment: Tal vez [este link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47935479/can-i-retrieve-paged-rows-and-total-count-within-a-single-query) de SO en inglés te ayude

Comment: Creo que la forma más rápida y segura de resolverlo es haciendo otra consulta: `SELECT COUNT(*) ...` aparte de la otra. De hecho, independiente del método (mysqli, pdo, etc...) se aconseja seguir esta forma porque no siempre num_rows trae los valores correctos en un SELECT.

Comment: Lo más rapida sería obtener totdos productos a la vez. Tu aplicación puede entonces mostrar el número total de los productos, porque ya lo sabe y mostrar los primeros 10 productos y esconder los demás. Si eso es demasiado memoría tienes que hacer lo que dice aeportugal (`SELECT COUNT(*)`).

Comment: Cuidado: Una consulta sin `ORDER BY` puede dar las filas en cualquier orden. Así puede pasar que `LIMIT 10,10` te da productos que ya recibiste con `LIMIT 0,10`, porque es otra consulta con possiblemente otro orden. Entonces hay que usar `ORDER BY` cuando usamos `LIMIT`. Esto nos dice que el DBMS tiene que ordenar los datos cada vez de nuevo. Por eso este tipo de paginacíon es lento. Es mejor usar el criterio del orden. Por ejemplo ordenas los productos con su ID. Entonces consultas los primeros diez y memorizas su maximo ID. La proxima vez consultas los primeros diez con un ID mas grande etc.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias a todos por sus comentarios. Lo que estaba buscando es "COUNT(*)" como mencionaron!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

podrías incluir en tu consulta una subconsulta que recupere la cantidad total de productos y utilizar la funcion COUNT pasandole el id de los productos, esto te entregara la cantidad total de productos en tu base de datos, esta consulta quedaria similar a esto:

```
SELECT COUNT(idProducto) FROM productos
```

Luego esta función la puedes incluir en tu consulta SQL de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(p.idProducto) FROM productos as p) as cantidadTotalProductos FROM products WHERE idEmpresa = $idEmpresa LIMIT $page,10
```

Es importante asignarle un alias a la tabla en tu subconsulta ya que si no me equivoco podría provocar un error al estar haciendo una consulta a la misma tabla.

Saludos.

Comment: Probé con "COUNT(*)" y logré lo que buscaba. Muchas gracias por tu respuesta Diego, muy informativa y concisa.